# Laravel 5.6 adding javascript library in public folder "Page not found"

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to include the hello-week javascript calendar to my laravel code.
https://github.com/maurovieirareis/hello-week

The package is installed using the npm method and I have it in the public directory:
"project_root"/public/node_modules/hello-week

When I try to include it using

```
<script src="{{ url('/') }}/public/node_modules/hello-week/dist/helloweek.min.js"></script>
```

I get

```
GET http://homestead.test/public/node_modules/hello-week/dist/helloweek.min.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Remove `public` from your URL. If your web server is configured corrected, `public` is your document root so you wouldn't specify it.

Comment: Thank you, that indeed solved the issue of not being able to find the .js file. It is however not showing anything except for the "prev" and "next" buttons. No errors are displayed anymore.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the calendar, so without specific code and troubleshooting, I can't help. I'd suggest looking at the browser error console, make sure the configuration is correct, and make sure the data is loaded correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use helper function `asset()`,
try this

```
asset('node_modules/hello-week/dist/helloweek.min.js),
```

`asset()` target `public folder`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, you are correct as is aynber in the comment on my post. This does resolve the issue of the page not found but the script is not executing. (there are no errors in the console log). I'll create a new question for this later after some extra research.